# How to dynamically change color of clicked elements using color-picker

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to change color according to user preference dynamically like when a user selects a color then it is applied synchronously to the element .

**Like when an element is clicked color picker opens and then it works like developer tools color-picker , when a color is chosen from the picker it is applied to element and if user wants to change the color again in same picker than that also applied**

Tried to went through following questions but couldn't find answer :

[Change background colors dynamically using input event](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55081702/16846346)

[how to dynamically select a color from a color picker by using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61258851/16846346)

[HTML Input Color Picker, Apply Changes In Sync With Color Picker Selection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67617275/16846346)

**I wanted to code work like this in below snippet, whichever element is clicked than colors are changes of that element.**

> In original code html is like this :
> `<div id="clockOuterCircle"><div id="clockStyleCircle"></div></div>` which can be solved by bubbling/capturing

```js
var reed = document.getElementById("clockOuterCircle");
var reed1 = document.getElementById("clockStyleCircle");
reed.addEventListener('click', deed)
reed1.addEventListener('click', deed)

function deed() {
  var reed2 = document.getElementById("colorClock");
  reed2.click();
  var reed3 = reed2.value;
  // reed1.addEventListener('change', function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = reed3;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = reed3;
  //})
}
```

```css
#clockStyleCircle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16vw;
  height: 16vw;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0%;
  top: 28.5%;
  left: 28.5%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(255, 233, 35);
}

#clockOuterCircle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 42vw;
  height: 42vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgb(255, 62, 62);
  background-color: rgb(253, 133, 133);
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockStyleCircle"></div>
<div id="clockOuterCircle"></div>
<div id="demo"></div>
<input type="color" name="colorClock" id="colorClock">
```

**Possible answer of dynamically changing color can be like this in below snippet, like using

`input`    event separately on each element.**

```js
var reed = document.getElementById("clockOuterCircle");
var reed1 = document.getElementById("clockStyleCircle");
reed.addEventListener('click', deed)
reed1.addEventListener('click', deed)

//function deed() {
//  var reed2 = document.getElementById("colorClock");
//  reed2.click();
//  var reed3 = reed2.value;
// reed1.addEventListener('change', function() {
// this.style.backgroundColor = reed3;
// document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = reed3;
//})
//}

reed2 = document.getElementById("colorClock");
reed2.addEventListener('input', deed)

function deed() {
  var reed3 = reed2.value;
  reed.style.backgroundColor = reed3;
}

reed4 = document.getElementById("colorClock2");
reed4.addEventListener('input', deed1)

function deed1() {
  var reed5 = reed4.value;
  reed1.style.backgroundColor = reed5;
}
```

```css
#clockStyleCircle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16vw;
  height: 16vw;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0%;
  top: 28.5%;
  left: 28.5%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(255, 233, 35);
}

#clockOuterCircle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 42vw;
  height: 42vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgb(255, 62, 62);
  background-color: rgb(253, 133, 133);
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockStyleCircle"></div>
<div id="clockOuterCircle"></div>
<div id="demo"></div>
<input type="color" name="colorClock" id="colorClock">
<input type="color" name="colorClock" id="colorClock2">
```

**But in above method color is not changing of clicked element instead a fixed element color is changed which is defined beforehand . So have to apply code to different elements separately, as there are many elements so wanted to apply both ways**

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: You can use events to fire a function that change color or make a custom color picker.

Comment: @naxsi yes I tried that but have to apply separately for different elements

Comment: if u wanna change dynamically, do a custom color picker or use some library like [jscolor](https://jscolor.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated to stop bubbling with `event.stopPropagation()`

If I've understood you correctly, you want to launch a colour picker every time any particular element in your page is clicked which allows you to change that element's background colour.

This solution adds and then launches a colour picker when any element with the class `circle` is clicked, then removes it again after a colour has been selected.

The colour picker input is hidden with `display:none` but the dialog box is visible.

```js
let body = document.body;
let circles = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');


circles.forEach((circle) => {

  circle.addEventListener('click', () => {
  
    let existingColourPickers = document.querySelectorAll('input.colour-picker')
    
    existingColourPickers.forEach((existingColourPicker) => {
    
      if (body.contains(existingColourPicker)) {
        body.removeChild(existingColourPicker);
      }
    
    });
        
    event.stopPropagation();
    let colourPicker = document.createElement("input");
       
    colourPicker.type = "color";
    colourPicker.className = "colour-picker";
    body.appendChild(colourPicker); 
    colourPicker.click();
    
    colourPicker.addEventListener("input", () => {
      circle.style.backgroundColor = event.target.value;
    }, false);
    
    colourPicker.addEventListener("change", () => {
      body.removeChild(colourPicker);
    }, false);
    
  });
  
});
```

```css
#clockStyleCircle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16vw;
  height: 16vw;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0%;
  top: 28.5%;
  left: 28.5%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(255, 233, 35);
  z-index:1;
}

#clockOuterCircle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 42vw;
  height: 42vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgb(255, 62, 62);
  background-color: rgb(253, 133, 133);
  user-select: none;
}

#another-circle {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px green solid;
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
}
.colour-picker {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="clockOuterCircle" class="circle">
    <div id="clockStyleCircle" class="circle"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- another circle -->
  <div id="another-circle" class="circle"></div>
  <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks @dave this is what I wanted to do , you solved it accurately

Comment: Can you tell about the changes in code when `<div id="clockOuterCircle"><div id="clockStyleCircle"></div></div>` instead of `<div id="clockStyleCircle" class="circle"></div><div id="clockOuterCircle" class="circle"></div>`

Comment: If you add the same class (e.g `circle`) to multiple elements on a page, you can use Javascript to listen for a click on any element that has that class.  In this case `circle.addEventListener('click' ...` means that any element with the `circle` class will respond to a click. So we add a colour input to the page when that happens, then apply the colour to that clicked element.

Comment: Wanted to know the change in code when `html` is `<div id="clockOuterCircle" class="circle"><div id="clockStyleCircle" class="circle"></div></div>` instead of `<div id="clockStyleCircle" class="circle"></div><div id="clockOuterCircle" class="circle"></div>`

Comment: As they are inside of other so when any of the circle clicked outer circle background-color is only changed

Comment: Right, gotcha. I've added `event.stopPropagation()` to the click event to stop the click event bubbling upwards.

Comment: Also what is the use of `false` in the `addEventListener` yiu used

Comment: One last question : Why calling a `html` `input='color' instead of creating `color-picker` has different behavior . I will post an answer you can look into it .

Comment: When the user don't select any color color-picker remain created and not removed , this keeps on creating color-picker when not selecting any color but just clicking the circles.

Comment: Don't tell about another question (**I have deleted that comment**) . Plz tell queries related to this question only

Comment: Hi @Rana, I've added a feature to check if there are any existing colour pickers and remove them (for if the user clicks away and doesn't select a colour)

Answer (score 1):

What you had was pretty close. I just separated the color picking code into a new function. Try this..

```js
var reed = document.getElementById("clockOuterCircle");
var reed1 = document.getElementById("clockStyleCircle");
reed.addEventListener('click', deed)
reed1.addEventListener('click', deed)

async function deed() {
  var color = await getUserColor();
  this.style.backgroundColor = color;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = color;
}

function getUserColor() {
  return new Promise(done => {
    var color_picker = document.createElement('input');
    color_picker.setAttribute('type', 'color');
    color_picker.style.opacity = 0;
    document.body.appendChild(color_picker);
    color_picker.addEventListener('change', function() {
      var color = this.value;
      this.remove();
      done(color);
    });
    color_picker.click();
  });
}
```

```css
#clockStyleCircle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16vw;
  height: 16vw;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0%;
  top: 28.5%;
  left: 28.5%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(255, 233, 35);
}

#clockOuterCircle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 42vw;
  height: 42vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgb(255, 62, 62);
  background-color: rgb(253, 133, 133);
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="clockStyleCircle"></div>
<div id="clockOuterCircle"></div>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: Can it is possible to change the colors dynamically without use of library like when user selects color in picker then it is applied instantly and also changes also applied instant

Comment: Can you elaborate your code plz , it is hard to understand

Comment: @Rana - I didn't use any libraries. It's all super simple, basic javascript. Tell me which part you want me to elaborate on.

Comment: `async` `await` `new Promise` `done(color)` are some parts I don't understand . Also does this code : `document.body.appendChild(color_picker);this.remove();` add picker at start of execution and remove picker  after getting value of color

Comment: [async and await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) are syntactic sugar for using [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). And yes... It creates an invisible color picker, clicks on it, and when the user choose a color it removes the color picker and returns the chosen color.

Comment: Thanks for the help you have used code without library but  can it be possible to do like in question second snippet that if color chosen then it is applied before  closing the picker and user choose a different color then that too changed like dev tools color picker

Answer (score 1):

Your example defines the *background-color* using two different methods *class* and *style*, which may produce unexpected results.

Here is an example using the most basic form of JavaScript, that does not set the *background-color* via *class*.

When you click an area, it will change to the selected color and when you select a color, the last area clicked, will change to the same color.

To keep it brief and simple, the example does not check, if the elements it operates on, are well defined.

```js
// The last area clicked
var div_last_clicked = 0;

// Called when the document has finished loading
function myonload() {
    // Detect when an area is clicked
    let elems = document.querySelectorAll('.mydiv');
    for(let i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
        let elem = elems[i];
        elem.addEventListener('click', mydiv_clicked);
    }
    // Detect when the color changes
    let ob = document.querySelector('.mycolor');
    ob.addEventListener('change', mycolor_changed);
}

// Called when an area is clicked
function mydiv_clicked(e) {
    let ob = document.querySelector('.mycolor');
    div_last_clicked = e.target;
    div_last_clicked.style = "background-color:" + ob.value;
}

// Called when the color changes
function mycolor_changed(e) {
    if(div_last_clicked)
        div_last_clicked.style = "background-color:" + e.target.value;
}
```

```css
.mydiv {
    height:30px;
    width: 200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    margin-bottom:2px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="myonload()">
    <input class="mycolor" type="color" value="#ff0000" />
    <p>When you click an area below, it will change to the selected color.</p>
    <p>When you change the color, the last area clicked will also change
        to the same color.</p>
    <div class="mydiv">First area</div>
    <div class="mydiv">Second area</div>
    <div class="mydiv">Third area</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your additional info, if you want to have a single colour input on the page, you can add a `data-id` attribute to each of your circles, and use that as a reference for which element the colour input should update when changed:

```js
var restyleBG = document.querySelectorAll(".restyleBackground")
var colorPicker = document.getElementById("colorClock");
var selected;

restyleBG.forEach((restyle) => {
  restyle.addEventListener('click', changeBGcolor, false)
})

function changeBGcolor(event) {
  event.stopPropagation()
  selected = document.querySelector(`[data-id="${event.srcElement.dataset.id}"]`);
  colorPicker.click();
}

colorPicker.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  selected.style.backgroundColor = colorPicker.value;
})
```

```css
#clockStyleCircle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16vw;
  height: 16vw;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0%;
  top: 28.5%;
  left: 28.5%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(255, 233, 35);
  z-index: 1;
}

#clockOuterCircle {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 42vw;
  height: 42vw;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid rgb(255, 62, 62);
  background-color: rgb(253, 133, 133);
  user-select: none;
}

#another-circle {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px green solid;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}

#colorClock {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="color" name="colorClock" id="colorClock">

  <div id="clockOuterCircle" class="restyleBackground" data-id="1">
    <div id="clockStyleCircle" class="restyleBackground" data-id="2"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- another circle -->
  <div id="another-circle" class="restyleBackground" data-id="3"></div>
  <!-- ... -->
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @dave , can you tell about `${event.srcElement.dataset.id}` . Also about restyle.addEventListener('click', changeBGcolor, `false`) : what is the use of `false`  here , sometimes it is true can you tell about this too.